# TikZ-Feynman: Reversing direction of momentum arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, tikz-feynman

I am trying to draw the Feynman diagram for Compton scattering.
I have come up with the following diagram, which is perfect except the leftmost arrow faces the wrong direction (I want it to denote incoming wavelength, so it should face towards the vertex).

IMAGE:

[image]

Does anyone know how to change the direction of this arrow?

```
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\feynmandiagram [scale=1.2, horizontal=f2 to f3] {
f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] f2 -- [fermion] f3 -- [fermion] f4 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
f2  -- [photon, edge label'=\(\gamma\), momentum=\(\lambda\)] p1,
f3 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\), momentum'=\(\lambda'\)] p2,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the documentation of `tikz-feymann` to the page 21,

[image]

there is the option: **reversed momentum**. Here the MWE with your request.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
   \feynmandiagram [scale=1.2, horizontal=f2 to f3] {
f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] f2 -- [fermion] f3 -- [fermion] f4 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
f2  -- [photon, edge label'=\(\gamma\), reversed momentum=\(\lambda\)] p1,
f3 -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\), momentum'=\(\lambda'\)] p2,
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works.